# Regex: Greedy matching some patterns ~-11 or ~6 etc?

Tags: regex

I have some text with following pattern

~, and optionally a - then some digits

So I can have (can be part of some larger text)

```
~7
~-6
~-11534
~-0
```

for example my text can be:

```
New Zealand~1 expenditure~-900
```

Right now I am using this pattern:

```
[~-]*[0-9]*[0-9]
```

It seems to does the work but I know [0-9]*[0-9] is greedy matching (0 to unlimited times)

I am wondering if there is a better pattern?

Comment: If I understand correctly, there can only be one `~` and then at most one `-`? Because that's not what your regex checks for. Your pattern would match `5` or `~~~~----~3` or `-~2`.

Comment: @Steven is that your whole string or do you want to match that pattern out of a larger text? Which tool/language do you use?

Comment: @SebastianProske pattern out of a larger text, I will edit my question.

Comment: @StevenYong I double-checked your new example, `~-?[0-9]+` will extract 2 substrings just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** Actually, to match your requirements better, I suggest

```
~-?[0-9]+
```

This way we specify that `~` required, and it can be followed by `-` and digits.
The question mark after a quantifier says to take as little as possible, making it non-greedy, *but in current example it is unnecessary*.

**EDIT 2:** I noticed rather lately that the digits are not entirely optional, and changed 'zero or more' quantifier `*` to 'one or more' quantifier `+`.

**EDIT 3:** To talk about 'greedy' and 'non-greedy'. A non-greedy algorithm would return as little as possible, and in case of multiple digits at the end of string it would include only the first one into result, which is not what you're looking for.

A bit more about greedy and non-greedy algorithms, thanks to [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) for excellently formulated explanation:

> The lazy quantifier at the end of the pattern will match 0 (if *? is used) or 1 (if +? is used) chars. That happens because the lazily quantified patterns only grab what they must match first (the minimum number of occurrences) and are skipped so that the subsequent patterns could be checked. Only if there is no match the engine goes back to the lazily quantified subpattern to expand it one more char and retry.

Comment: You should test this pattern that will systematically match an empty string.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte what do you mean?

Comment: @StevenYong Yep, I see. Lets just remove the last question mark, and tell me if that's what you were looking for.

Comment: "multiple digits at the end of string" should be read as "multiple digits". The lazy quantifier *at the end of the pattern* will match 0 (if `*?` is used) or 1 (if `+?` is used) chars. That happens because the lazily quantified patterns only grab what they must match first (the minimum number of occurrences) and are skipped so that the subsequent patterns could be checked. Only if there is no match the engine goes back to the lazily quantified subpattern to expand it one more char and retry.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that's exactly what I meant. Do you think I should clarify that a little more in my answer?

Comment: @StevenYong: the pattern was `[~-]*?[0-9]*?` when I wrote this comment, since all terms are optional and the quantifiers are non-greedy, the pattern will succeed at each position in the string with an empty match *(whatever the string is)*.